# Как установить новейший clang по умолчанию?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, clang

Решил перейти с `gcc` на `clang`: скачал новейший clang, доступный на дефолтном репозитории (4.0). При этом при запуске `clang -o prog prog.c -Wall` - используется более старый компилятор, а новый доступен, только при `clang-4.0 -o prog prog.c -Wall`. Как установить новый `clang` по умолчанию? И еще вопрос: не подскажете репозиторий с новейшим `clang-5.0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Способ с ручным переводом ссылок печален. Скорее всего при следующем обновлении все либо затрется по умолчанию, либо станет колом.

Но специально для Вашего случая давно придумана [система альтернатив](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternatives).

самый простой способ (он на самом деле очень похож на cпособ @diraria) заключается в следующем. Вначале нужно "проинсталлить"

```
sudo update-alternatives \
  --install /usr/bin/clang   clang   /usr/bin/clang-4.0     50 \
  --slave   /usr/bin/clang++ clang++ /usr/bin/clang++-4.0  \
  --slave   /usr/bin/lldb    lldb    /usr/bin/lldb-4.0 \
  --slave   /usr/bin/lldb-server lldb-server /usr/bin/lldb-server-4.0
```

(пути проверяйте и корректируйте!).

Теперь, в любой момент можно запустить такую команду

```
sudo update-alternatives --config clang
```

и выбрать нужную версию компилятора. Параметр slave позволяет к "мастер имени" подключить несколько привязанных.

Также не забывайте, что кроме собственно clang, нужно и соответствующий llvm подтянуть. Полные наборы команд [здесь](https://gist.github.com/RaymondKroon/da6650bc72630b963a44).

А вот [здесь](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905205/installing-clang-5-0-and-using-c17) описано, как собрать самому свеженький clang.

краткий перевод

вначале добавим llvm.org репозиторий:

```
deb http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-5.0 main
```

для этого откроем редактор

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/llvm.list
```

Также добавим ключ репозитория

```
wget -O - http://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

теперь обновим список

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Теперь ставим нужный компилятор

```
sudo apt-get install clang-5.0 lldb-5.0 lld-5.0
```

Теперь все уже должно работать

Если хочется посмотреть список всего, что есть в этом репозитории, то нужна  такая команда

```
grep -i package: /var/lib/apt/lists/apt.llvm* | cut -f3 -d: | sort | uniq
```

будет список вида

```
clang-5.0 
clang-5.0-doc 
clang-5.0-examples 
libclang-common-5.0-dev
...
```

естестенно, можно выбрать другую версию.

Comment: Способ с ручным переводом ссылок ни чем не хуже: update-alternatives уважает этот выбор, о чём прямо написано в мане...

Comment: Это линукс. Если пользователь хочет бриться бензопилой - это его выбор. Но если отрежет голову - это его выбор.

Comment: это задокументированная возможность, а не какой-то хак... ток что вполне имеет право на существование...

Comment: я же абсолютно не против. Если пользователь понимает, что делает и хорошо все помнит, то хоть ручками набивать байты.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr:** `ln -sf $(which clang-4.0) $(which clang)`

Вероятно способ не самый хороший, но всё-таки:

1. С помощью команды `which` определяем расположение файла для команды `clang`. Например у меня `which clang` выдаёт путь `/usr/bin/clang`
2. Смотрим на файл полученный в предыдущем пункте, скорее всего это будет [символическая ссылка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0). Например у меня `/usr/bin/clang` является символической ссылкой на `/usr/bin/clang-5.0`
3. Перезаписываем этот файл, чтобы он являлся символической ссылкой на исполняемый файл для `clang-4.0` (расположение которого находим той же командой `which`:

   ```
   ln -sf /usr/bin/clang-4.0 /usr/bin/clang
   ```

   пояснения:

   - [`ln`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ln_(UNIX)) — команда для создания ссылок. Имеет синтаксис `ln файл имя_ссылки`
   - флаг `-s` — создавать символическую ссылку вместо жёсткой
   - флаг `-f` — не выдавать ошибку, если создаваемый файл-ссылка существует